# compare 2 files and show only lines with partial matches

Tags: linux, bash, command-line

file #1 example:

```
one two three 
four five six 
seven eight nine
eleven
```

file #2 example:

```
 two
 five
 nine.not
 eleven
```

I would like to find **any** lines on the file #1 that contain any word present on file #2, example output:

```
one two three
four five six 
eleven
```

I was trying to see if there's a way to do it in the linux command line, but have not been successful yet. any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can try:

```
grep -f file2 file1
```

-f option obtain patterns from file2 (one per line)

**edit**

@Barmar comment

```
grep -F -w -f file2 file1
```

with -w option, lines like `eleveneleven` are not selected

Comment: Use `-F` option to perform exact matching instead of regexp, and `-w` to match whole words.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this awk command:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1]; next} {for (i in a) if (index($0, i)) print}' file2 file1
one two three
four five six
eleven
```